# conditional extraction of data from dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, if-statement, extract

I have a data frame as shown below. What I want to do is, for example, the Aston Martin car is 4 years old, so I have to pull the relevant data from the year4_6 column. Or the Honda car is 7 years old, so I should use the year7_11 data.

I tried to write an if-else statement but I couldn't. I wonder what kind of code can I write for this, should I use a package?

```
hub.cc     hub.make hub.age hub.year1_3 hub.year4_6 hub.year7_11
1300 Aston Martin       4         480         335          189
1800       Toyota       1        1352        1059          624
2000        Honda       7        2129        1642          965
1600        Honda       9         768         576          335
```

Comment: Do the _3, _6 and _11 have any meaning or system? Or could you drop them for convenience?

Comment: no, it is something that I created just to understand what year intervals those data fall into :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the `column_name` string using the `paste()` function and then select that column.
The issue here is that the suffixes `_3`, `_6` and `_11` are inconvenient. So I will use the `starts_with` functionality of the `tidyverse` packages.

for row 3:

```
library(tidyverse)
age = df[3, "hub.age"]
column_name = paste("hub.year", age, sep="")
data = df %>% 
       slice(3) %>% 
       select(starts_with(column_name))
```

If you drop the suffixes (so you columns are named `hub.year1, hub.year4, hub.year7`), it simplifies a lot. Then, you can use the following base R syntax for column referencing: `df[, 'column_name']`.

for row 3 again:

```
age = df[3, "hub.age"]
column_name = paste("hub.year", age, sep="")
data = df[3, column_name]
```

If the data is small, you can just iterate over the dataframe with a for loop and replace `3` with `i` to get the data for all rows. If the data is big, you might wanna use something like `mutate()` from the tidyverse.

**Note:** I did not test the code above since you did not provide the data in a convenient reproducible way using `dput`. If the answer does not meet your expectations, please clarify and provide the data e.g. with `dput`.

Comment: thank you very much, actually, I found another method but this is much more efficient and advanced!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Happy to hear that. If the answer resolved your question, please consider marking it as accepted with the gray check to its left.